# Storing complex types in Entity Framework

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have created a database using the edmx designer in an ASP.NET MVC project.  This has a number of tables like this:

- An Office can have many Locations
- Each Location can have many Staff
- Each Location has Location Type
- Each Location has a Business Type
- Each Location has a Browser Version
- Each Browser Version has a Browser

The details of this are probably unimportant.  The core class is `Staff`, it has a `Location` property, which has an `Office` property, a `LocationType` property, a `BusinessType` property and a `Browser Version` property (which has the `Browser` property).

I'm creating a registration form. I started by trying to create a Staff member instance to save by using code like `staffMember.Location.LocationType = DB.Locations(l => l.Id = model.Id);`
which populated the class with fully populated class instances.  Calling the save method at this point would blow up with :

> Entities in 'DBContainer.BrowserVersions' participate in the
>   'BrowserBrowserVersion' relationship. 0 related 'Browsers' were found.
>   1 'Browsers' is expected.

Now, again, the BrowserVersion.Browser class was correctly populated.

So, I did some reading, and as a result I made sure my code always uses the same DBContext.  This did not fix my issue.  So I changed my code to do something like this:

`staffMember.Location.BrowserType = new BrowserType { Id = myBrowserType.Id };`

This would then blow up with an error like :

> {"Cannot insert the value NULL into column 'BrowserName', table
>   'MyProject.dbo.Browsers'; column does not allow nulls. INSERT
>   fails.\r\nThe statement has been terminated."}

In the end I found I cannot use the objects copied from my DBContext, but I need to create objects that have all the relevant properties copied across from the objects I get from the DB. Surely I am doing something wrong, I'm writing more code now than if I used stored procs and my own data layer?

Comment: Do you want to create a new Location when creating a Staff member?

Comment: Yes, I do.  The location type, business type, browser version and browser are selected from a drop list, so they are never added.  I tried adding them in order, that is, adding the location, then the office, then the staff member, but, when I add one, it adds them all, when I finally got it working, adding the location actually saved all the data to the DB.  So, I don't see any way to add the location without also adding the other stuff associated with it, but the errors always relate to the items already in the DB.

Comment: When I provide the browser id AND name, and the version id AND name, then it does not add a new record, it correctly associates with the existing one, but if I just provide the id, I get the null reference exception, it seems to check if the value can be null BEFORE checking if the value is already in the DB.

Comment: Turn off validation in `DbContext`.

Comment: How do I do that ? Doesn't that mean I'm turning off what the system is supposed to do for me ? Will that then find the entities that already have that id, or try to create new ones ? Is this the best way to get it to work ?  This is a learning project, so I am trying to learn best practices, not just have it run.

Comment: what does one do in this situation, where my question was not answered and has been lost.  Do I post it again, or try to bump this one ?